# Vue 3 Object property returns undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, keycloak, vuejs3

How to extract other attributes from Keycloak object ?
Right now,

**If i use,**

```
console.log(keycloak)
```

*it will output whole keycloak object. Even if i reload it stays there on console.*

**But when i use,**

```
console.log(keycloak.token)
```

*It will output token from keycloak object but when i reload the page it gives me undefined on console.*

**My Vue Component:**

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    {{ arrowFunction() }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { useKeycloak } from "@baloise/vue-keycloak";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Home",

  setup() {
    const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();
    function arrowFunction() {
      console.log(keycloak);
      return keycloak;
    }
    return {
      arrowFunction,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

**My Main.ts:**

```
import { vueKeycloak } from "@baloise/vue-keycloak";
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(vueKeycloak, {
  initOptions: {
    onLoad: "login-required", // default
  },
  config: {
    url: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/auth/",
    realm: "xxxxx",
    clientId: "xxxxclient",
  },
});
createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount("#app");
```

**Infos are stored here:**
[image]

Comment: is the object fetched with an asynchronous function, or better said: Is it possible, that keycloak holds a Promise at any given point in time?

Comment: I really don't know the answer of ur question, as i am a newbie. But here can u see the library m using, it has very compact information, which can hopefully answer ur question.

https://github.com/baloise/vue-keycloak

Comment: Please see the image which i just added to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [README](https://github.com/baloise/vue-keycloak#usekeycloak) of the keycloak package shows that the `useKeycloak()` exposes a few states. One of them seems to be what you wanted to get in the first place (token).

So I'd suggest that instead of only fetching the keycloak Property and trying to get token of that, you might want to get the state you're looking for directly and therefore, I would rewrite your code to

```
  setup() {
    const { keycloak, token } = useKeycloak();
    function arrowFunction() {
      console.log(keycloak);
      console.log(token);
      return keycloak;
    }
    return {
      arrowFunction,
    };
  },
```

I never worked with the library, so tell me when I'm missing a major thing, but I think this should work as you want.

---

**Further elaboration:**

If we take a look at the documentation of `useKeycloak();` we can see that it will return an Object with various Properties. Among those we have keycloak and token.

We are getting the properties of that Object directly by destructuring them on the call.

```
const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();
```

will be the same as

```
const ReturnValue = useKeycloak();
const keycloak = ReturnValue.keycloak;
```

So we can bind the desired exposed property of the return value by adding it in the curly brackets resulting in:

```
const { keycloak, token } = useKeycloak();
// Same as:
// const ReturnValue = useKeycloak();
// const keycloak = ReturnValue.keycloak;
// const token = ReturnValue.token;
```

So what happened initially was, that you were effectively logging `console.log(useKeycloak().keycloak.token);`

Comment: i added ur code and getting 7 errors.
But for keycloak and token i am getting this.

Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'token'. Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'keycloak'.

As i said, we have other errors too for other properties.

Comment: Did you add the example? That was just to show a snippet of the documentation. 
What happens when you just add the token in `const { keycloak, token } = useKeycloak();` and `console.log(token)`

Comment: I did add the example and changed code as u suggested in above comment.
It didn't work as expected until i changed it in console.log(token.value); ..

Now i am getting output as expected.
Thanks, can you please elaborate what did i miss and why it is working now?

Comment: @DnD2k21 I added a bit of elaboration